# Advice needed on learning maths oneself

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I am a master's student in physics trying to learn maths on my own. My classes workload is heavy and the schedule is very hectic due to which I don't get time to do mathematics.

I have done Linear algebra and differential geometry to the beginners level and now currently I am trying to learn topology from Munkres and I plan to learn Differential geometry,Real and Complex Analysis, Groups and fields and Functional Analysis.

I know this is quite a lot of work in front of me considering I am in master's and I would never finish it of along with physics but what I really need is consistency which I have found could only be gained if I follow some video lectures because reading only from books makes me feel I am in a dense forest all alone.

Are there any good video lectures or notes on the beginners to intermediate level on these topics?

Due to my inexperience any advice given would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ever consider transferring to Master's of Math? It does not make sense to learn Physics courses when your real interest is in Math. BTW, Math may give you better job perspective than Physics.

Comment: @verdelite Actually a lot of times but right now I am in a real dilemma as currently I am doing my master's in physics and have very little exposure in maths, so will I get any admission in maths master's program?

Comment: Do you want to learn math for physics? Or just because you like math? If it's the latter, this question is probably better suited for math.stackexchange

Comment: @AcademicBot well it is both. I like mathematics because it is much more rigorous than hand waviness of physics.

Comment: @RandomXYZ It is easy to transfer within the same University. Make appointments to several Math professors, talk to each of them for 30 minutes, ask for their advises.